# Why do upper case letters come before lower case letters in the ASCII table?

Tags: ascii, uppercase, lowercase

In one of my interview, the interviewer asked me why the upper case letters are before the lower case letters in ASCII table, I searched on google.com but found nothing, could anyone gave me the answer? Thx a lot!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm only guessing, but I imagine it's because the earliest character sets had no lowercase at all. The Baudot telegraph code was only 5 bits, and CDC mainframes natively used a 6-bit code; there was no room for lowercase. When ASCII was developed as a 7-bit code which finally had enough room for lowercase letters, they were considered something of a luxury add-on, so it made sense to put them in the back half of the set.

Of course, we can dive a little deeper and ask why that attitude exists; historically, upper case came first and was the only shape the letters had for centuries or even millennia before the idea of case distinction was invented. For most folks literate in a language that uses the Latin alphabet, uppercase is the base form; you learn it first, the archetype of each letter is the capital shape, etc.

But it's worth noting that this ordering *is* nonetheless specific to ASCII, and not necessarily true of other character sets; for example, EBCDIC has the lowercase letters first. Commodore microcomputers could switch between two character sets, and even though both were based on ASCII, the one with lowercase letters had them first. (The other set had extra graphic characters in place of lowercase.)

Unicode has taken its cue from ASCII (and the extended-Latin character sets based on it), so most of the alphabets that have case distinctions have the uppercase versions come first within their code blocks. But there are exceptions, and of course many alphabets don't have case distinctions at all, while others have more complicated relationships than our simple 1-to-1 mapping.

Comment: it sounds really make sense! but I don't get the meaning of "and have the 32-bit as a sort of inverse "shift flag" to indicate lowercase.", what is that mean? thx again!

Comment: Uppercase A is decimal 65, binary 1000001.  Lowercase A is decimal 97, binary 1100001.  The only difference is that second bit from the left, which changed from 0 to 1.  That bit has the value of 32 (which is why the decimal went from 65 to 65+32=97), so I called it "the 32-bit".  It's functioning as a "flag" because you can look at only that bit and tell something: in this case, whether the letter is upper- or lowercase.  Case is associated with the shift key on the keyboard, so I called it a sort of "shift" flag, and it's "inverse" because the flag is set (1) for the _un_-shifted letters.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when sorting strings you want 'a' to come before 'b' and the character code of 'a' is less (smaller) than 'b'.

The same thing with uppercase. 'A' is before 'a'.

That way you can easily sort 'Anthony' before 'ant', just by comparing character codes, even though lowercase 'anthony' would normally appear just after 'ant' due to length.

That would have made sorting strings very complex if uppercase has larger character codes than lowercase.

As 'Slaks' mentioned however...Unicode makes it more complicated in you have characters such as  ȦAÁÀÂÄĀĂǍÃȂ,  which often have unicode numbers larger than 'a' but are generally considered sorting before 'a'.

Comment: Makes sense. I would suggest this as right answer.

Answer (score -1):

To make sure that lowercase letters don't come before uppercase letters when sorting text.

In the modern Unicode era, sorting text is far more complicated, but 20 years ago, you could sort text by ASCII values.

Comment: _Disclaimer_: Pure speculation

Comment: why the uppercase letters should go before the lowercase letters when sorting text? shouldn't it be the lowercase letters before the uppercase letters?( beg for my poor English.^^ )

Comment: this doesn't make sense.