# Yii2 grid sorting is not correct with ArrayDataProvider

Tags: yii2

I'm using array data provider for grid view widget since the data source is an API response. It's working fine, but when I try to sort the 'Name' column, it's  sorting incorrectly with the lowercase first letters. Please check the table grid screenshot. The API response which I'm receiving is correct with the current sorting.

**1. Table Grid**

[image: Click here to view]

**2. Model**

```
$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => @$response->data,
        'pagination' => false,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['id', 'name', 'shortDescription'],
        ],
    ]);
```

**3. View**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'  dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
       'id',
       'name',
       'shortDescription'
     ],
  'options' => ['class' => 'content'],
  'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-hover'],
  'summary' => Yii::t('app', 'Showing').' {begin}-{end} of '.$total.' '.Yii::t('app', 'items')
]); 
?>
```

Please guide me to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: The sort is correct, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994412/why-do-upper-case-letters-come-before-lower-case-letters-in-the-ascii-table). You can try to capitaliza all the first letter

Comment: Thanks @Sfili_81. That may be the only way I think..